# Django, Signals and another process

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, signals

I've got my Django project running well, and a separate background process which will collect data from various sources and store that data in an index.

I've got a model in a Django app called `Sources` which contains, essentially, a list of sources that data can come from! I've successfully managed to create a signal that is activated/called when a new entry is put in the `Sources` model.

My question is, is there a simple way that anybody knows of whereby I can send some form of signal/message to my background process indicating that the `Sources` model has been changed? Or should I just resort to polling for changes every x seconds, because it's *so* much simpler?

Many thanks for any help received.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough info about the background processes. What are they? Things run through Python `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Sorry - the background process is totally separate. Launched in the terminal by another command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unclear how are you running the background process you're talking about.

Anyway, I'd suggest that in your background task you use the `Sources` model directly. There are convenient ways to run the task without leaving realm of Django (so as to have an access to your models. You can use Celery [1], for example, or RQ [2].

Then you won't need to pass any messages, any changes to `Sources` model will take effect the next time your task is run.

[1] Celery is an open source asynchronous task queue/job queue, it isn't hard to set up and integrates with Django well.

- [Celery: general introduction](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)
- [Django with celery introduction](http://packages.python.org/django-celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html)

[2] RQ means "Redis Queue", it is ‘a simple Python library for queueing jobs and processing them in the background with workers’.

- [Introductory post](http://nvie.com/posts/introducing-rq/)
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nvie/rq)

Comment: Awesome, I think I shall give Celery a go. Many thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Polling is probably the easiest if you don't need split-second latency.

If you do, however, then you'll probably want to look into either, say,

- sending an UNIX signal (or other methods of IPC, depending on platform) to the process
- having the background process have a simple listening socket that you just send, say, a byte to (which is, admittedly, a form of IPC), and that triggers the action you want to trigger
- or some sort of task/message queue. [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) come to mind.